# InstallShield LE "Another version of this product is already registered"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-2011

I'm running into a roadblock using InstallShield LE in VS2010.  The second time running the resulting setup.exe (with incremented version numbers), I get the error

> Another version of this product is
>   already registered

By "incremented version numbers", I mean I changed the Minor Version, Build Number and Revision to larger numbers in AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion of my .exe (the DLL's are set to "1.0.*")

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.2.103.005")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.2.103.005")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("Alpha 0.1 - 2/8/2011")]
```

and also updated the Product Version in the General Information tab of the Installshield LE setup project from 0.10.0000 to 0.11.0000.

I did come across instances of this error message in other SO postings and on the manufacturer's community support forum, but did not find a solution that applies to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out the answer is to create an entry on the Upgrade Paths tab.  When you do that, InstallShield LE will present a file selection dialog.  If you have the old installer, presumably you can browse to it to get information about what version you wish to be able to upgrade from.  In my case I didn't have the old installer handy, so I pressed cancel and the new Upgrade Paths entry was created anyway.  I then adjusted the properties of that entry to specify a minimum and maximum version for the upgrade, and everything worked as expected.

**EDIT**

(from @lookatmike's comment)

You also have to change the Product Version and (somewhat counterintuitively) the Product Code in the general information tab. The Upgrade Code must stay the same.

Comment: Eric, this did not work for me. Did you do anything else of significance? I am incrementing the Product Version in the General Information tab, and I've added a Upgrade Path with a broad Min and Max version range than should include any previously installed version.

Comment: To expand on Eric's accepted answer above, in addition to specifying the upgrade path as he describes, you also have to change the Product Version and (somewhat counterintuitively) the Product Code in the general information tab. The Upgrade Code **must** stay the same.

Comment: @lookatmike: Thanks, I updated the answer with your comment.  It is also perfectly legitimate for you to just edit my answer (assuming you have the rep to do so).

Comment: THANK you! came back to an installer years later and totally forgot about the Product Code. (ISLE 2013)

Comment: If you change the product code you are essentially telling windows that it is a different product. So if you install your product 1.0, then upgrade to 1.2 with a different product code, the files of 1.0 will be overwritten but there will be 2 entries in the add remove programs list. Product Code shouldn't be changed for minor upgrades.

Answer (score 7):

OK - This problem was driving me CRAZY - and I haven't found a perfect answer online.

So I decided I was done screwing around.

This may not be the "BEST" way to solve the problem - I'm sure there is some convoluted MSI-based way of "handling this properly" but I couldn't figure it out (I guess I'm dumb?)

Basically my installer just makes sure .NET is installed, and copies some files into the Program Files directory, adds some registry entries, shortcuts, etc.

If you have a more complex installation procedure - I'd encourage you to find the "right" answer elsewhere. But for something simple like I've got (and I suspect 95% of people struggling with this problem have) this works just fine.

First - NEVER touch "Product Code". I believe this is correct procedure for MSIs across the board... you shouldn't be changing the product code. And this solution relies on that as well.

Next - Copy the product code to your clipboard - we'll need it in a second.

Basically, we're going to tell InstallShield to ALWAYS UNINSTALL THE PRODUCT if it already exists on the machine.

[image]

[image]

If you or your partners ever run the install SILENTLY - make sure you do this in both places:

[image]

For "File Name and Command Line", enter:

**`msiexec /uninstall {YOUR PRODUCT CODE HERE} /passive`**

That's it. Now your installer will always uninstall the old version.

**NOTE: THIS DISABLES ANY SORT OF "Am I running a newer version of the installer" CHECK.**

Comment: This is a great tutorial, but it appears to NOT apply to the Limited Edition version of InstallShield (ISLE).  At least for VS2012, you need to upgrade to one of the paid versions of InstallShield to get access to the "Before System Search" Custom Actions.

Answer (score 0):

I often reuse my Visual Studio projects and got this problem. As @Eric-j said I had to change the product code in the General Information tab of the VS Install Setup project:

[image]