# Installshield Express, another version of this product is already installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSI Install Fails because “Another version of this product is already installed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970862/msi-install-fails-because-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-installed)

I am getting a little bit frustrated from the Installshield express addon in visual studio. When I used the default installer from MS which is included in Visual Studio 2010 and I would like to create a new version of my product it ask to change the product code which I will do all the time and I can update my previous installations without any problem.

But when I do this in installshield I need to change this manualy (which is no problem) but I get several installs in the list add/remove programs.

There seems to be a way to remove the previuos version first but I do not get this to work.

THe only thing I would like is to have an update installed or if noting is installed there will be a fresh install.

What is the best way / approach to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the product code, you change the package code. If you change the product code, it will think it is a new product and when installed, it will create a new entry in add/remove. If you change the package code, it will think it is a new install, and try to upgrade your already installed product.

Basically you want to create a small update as defined here http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/MajorMinorSmall.htm

Comment: Looks like there's a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940701/installshield-le-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-registered

Comment: I had to go to "Organise Your Setup" and "General Information" and then look at the product / upgrade codes.