# How to perform an upgrade via MSI without command line parameters

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, installshield, installshield-2012

We have developed a basic MSI project with versions as - 1.0.00.00, 1.0.01.00, 1.1.00.00, 2.0.00.00 each of which will copy some text files to my preferred location.

With output as EXE,
I have first installed the project with version 1.0.00.00 and tried to upgrade to 1.0.01.00. This time, I was able to get a pop-up prompting whether I would like to perform an upgrade. This is the expected behavior and the upgrade was also successfully done.

The same upgrade had been done from 1.0.00.00 to 1.1.00.00 and also from 1.0.00.00 to 2.0.00.00 successfully.

With MSI as output,
I have done the same scenario as EXE. I have first installed the project with version 1.0.00.00 and tried to upgrade to 1.0.01.00. This time, I got a pop-up saying "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel".

I have tried to perform an upgrade via command prompt with the command

**"msiexec /i <MySetupPath\MyMsi.msi> REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vamus".**
This time the upgrade was succesfully performed.

I have tried to change the product code, package code and the UniqueID. All resulted in the same behavior.

To perform an upgrade via MSI, Right click on the MSI and give install does not seem to be working for me. Could you please let us know the correct scenario to perform an upgrade via MSI?

Install Shield version: 2015

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InstallShield LE "Another version of this product is already registered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940701/installshield-le-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-registered)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940701/installshield-le-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-registered